# Why doesn't Euler's theorem provide an *absolute* energy scale

Tags: thermodynamics

we know that for a one component system

$$U= TS - PV + N \mu$$

Now all terms on the right hand side have well defined zeros, but the internal energy is known to be a relative quantity, with no unique zero. What's going on?

Similarly, we derive the above from the fact that:

$$U(kS, kV, kN)= kU(S,V,N)$$

And it seems to me that taking $k=0$ gives us $U(0,0,0)=0$ - the internal energy of an empty system is the uniquely defined zero of energy.

Comment: Which Euler's theorem is this? Not any of these? -- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTheorem.html

Comment: @BenCrowell The one on homogeneous functions. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement *"the internal energy is known to be a relative quantity, with no unique zero"* refers probably to the fact that for common systems of thermodynamics that *do not lose or gain matter*, the First law of thermodynamics implies the internal energy is a function of temperature $T$ and volume $V$ such that addition of a constant independent of them has no consequence on the measurable quantities; the function

$$
U'(T,V) = U(T,V) + c~~~(1)
$$
is just as good as the function $U(T,V)$ and so **for given thermodynamic state of the system, no value of internal energy is preferred**.

<sub>Note that neither the function $U$ nor $c$ have $N$ as an argument here because the system does not change its molar number $N$. The relation 
$$
U = TS -PV + \mu N
$$
has no motivation here because $N$ does not appear at all.</sub>

However, when considering two or more systems of the same chemical species with the same temperature and pressure but different amount of matter, it is quite natural to assume that for given $T,P$ the internal energy is directly proportional to the molar number $N$ (additivity of energy). One introduces new function $\tilde{U}$ for it that expresses this:
$$
\tilde{U}(T,P,N) = N\tilde{U}(T,P,1)=N\tilde{u}(T,P),~~~(2)
$$
where $\tilde{u}$ is energy of one mole.
This does not follow from the 1st law of thermodynamics, but probably is an independent assumption that is very often true(it may not be true in some cases, for example when capillary forces play role.) This additivity together with other ideas about the entropy then lead to the relation $U=TS-PV+\mu N$.

This relation, however, does not mean that for given thermodynamic state, single value of the internal energy has been found; it only means that there is a relation between energy, entropy and chemical potential. The only quantity that is fixed in this equation is
$$
PV =  TS - U +\mu N
$$
since both $P$ and $V$ are measurable quantities, but entropy, energy or chemical potential are not. One can redefine at least two of them to give the same product $PV$ and other quantities.

<sub>In the rest of the post I will show that arbitrariness of $U$ translates into arbitrariness of $\tilde{u}$. For system with constant $N$, since we have two functions $U,U'$, let us assume there are corresponding two functions $\tilde{u},\tilde{u}'$ that give the appropriate values of energy for given state:
$$
U(T,V) = N\tilde{u}(T,P)
$$
$$
U'(T,V) = N\tilde{u}'(T,P)
$$
Combining the two equations (1),(2), we obtain
$$
N\tilde{u}'(T,P) = N\tilde{u}(T,P) + c
$$
The only way this can be true for system of any size is if the quantity $c$ is proportional to $N$. So actually $c$ is not always constant; it is constant only for systems that do not change their $N$. Generally
$$
c=\alpha N
$$
so the energy of one mole
$$
\tilde{u}'(T,P) = \tilde{u}(T,P)+\alpha
$$
is determined only up to an arbitrary constant $\alpha$.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I came to a similar conclusion after a little more thought: the relative state is literally that - a state defined say by a temperature and pressure but whose size may vary to be the size of the system we're interested in. I was imagining a box with a fixed amount of energy to which we compared all systems to.

Comment: One question though - you say entropy, energy and chemical potential are relative. I am under the impression entropy has a well defined zero, precisely when the temperature is 0. I see now that adjusting $U$ to $U+N\alpha $ changes $N \mu$ and $U$ in the same way, so that $U= TS - PV + \mu N$ holds after the change. So $\mu$ is relative, but I still don't see why $S$ isn't absolute, and how I can change $S$ in a system by fiddling with the relative nature of $U$.

Comment: To emphasize this again, I can develop an experimental method for measuring $S$, by starting at 0 Kelvin and adding energy and monitoring the temperature increase and evaluating $S= \int_0^{T_f} dQ/T $. There's no change in $N$ here, and we only need to measure energy flow and temperature, both of which are absolute. How then isn't entropy 'measurable' like pressure or volume?

Comment: Sorry, one more question. It seems natural to me that the *difference* in energy between a 1L balloon and a 2L balloon with the same composition is well defined. But according to what you've said this doesn't seem to be the case. If the 1L is said to have 1kJ of energy the 2L will have 2 kJ, and the difference will be 1kJ, but if the 1L is said to have 3kJ of energy the 2L will have 6 kJ, and the difference will be 4kJ. This is unintuitive to me (I feel this internal energy difference should be well defined)  but am I correct to reason that this energy difference is in fact not well defined?

Comment: OK, the more I think about this the more it makes sense: if we add even one more atom, how do we quantify the energy added? For instance, do we count relativistic mass-energy or not? It's impossible to define exactly how much energy we've added, without of course having a reference state telling us how much energy is in a mole of some state of matter. Still not sure on the entropy question though :)

Comment: @tom, by using the formula $S=\int_0^{T_f}dQ/T$ you are defining unique entropy. The definition itself is not unique, however, because $S=S_0+\int_0^{T_f}dQ/T$ would do just as well.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I think I understand: classical thermodynamics is consistent without assuming the 3rd law. Thanks for your help, I think this makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your arguments you're neglecting the potential energy from intermolecular forces, or should I say the chemical bonding energy of your system or even mass-energy of the atoms. Meaning that even if you consider the 0 Kelvin case and freeze all degrees of freedom (vibrational, transnational, rotational) you still cannot expect the internal energy $U$ to be zero.  This is taken care of by the internal chemical potential of each molecule, as $\mu$ is composed of two parts:

External $\mu_{\rm ext}$: electric potential, gravitational, ...

Internal $\mu_{\rm int}$: obtained from molar Gibbs free energy, contains all the dependencies on density, temperature, electrochemical potential, etc.

Finally your argument with coefficient $k$, if fulfilled, just shows that $U$ is extensive with respect to $(S,V,N)$, and does not really contribute to the problem at hand here.

Last but no least, even at $S=0$ i.e. a single microstate available to the system, things do not simplify that much as there is still residual motion in the system due to the uncertainty principle in the ground state.

Comment: Of course all this relies on the fact that matter at ground state is stable and will not further decay to none-existence! At least if we keep our framework within thermodynamics and statistical mechanics...

Comment: Why would there be potential energy due to intermolecular forces when there are no particles in the system? If you define potential energy as the function whose derivative is force, its zero is undefined: Empty system might as well have 10 potential energy. This doesn't make too much sense, as potential energy is physically supposed to be work that you can extract. The equation in the question implies that in thermodynamics indeed empty system has 0 energy. The addition of any interacting molecule would bring with it a nonunique potential energy, so I am not sure of the usefulness of said fact

Comment: @alarge when did I take $N=0$? please read carefully before commenting, I considered the case $T=0 K$ and $N\ne 0$, why would I talk about a system without particles?

Comment: The way I understood the original question is "Euler ($N=0$) seems to give an absolute scale of energy, but I know there should not be one: What's going on?" I assumed that any answer would only address the $N=0$ ($k=0$) case. If you indeed did not, I am sorry for the confusion. However, then I do not think yours is an answer to the asked question: It merely seems to reinforce the point that there should not be an absolute scale, something that is mentioned in the original question, but does not really address what is wrong with the derivation. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @alarge you were right to assume that from his question, but since I saw no point discussing about a system with no particles, so I figured he was off with his initial question and so replied with an answer for the case that the system does indeed contain a gas but at $T=0 K$. Since Tom doesn't seem to reply to anything, we're left with our assumptions :)

Comment: Finally it is likely that he was making the analogy with EM fields, where if one were to ask "what is the equilibrium state of an EM field?" the answer would be "the equilibrium of an EM field is when there's no EM field" :) , so maybe now with the internal energy of a gas, he's trying to make a point similar to this. But then again his OP was weird enough to begin with (and really lacked proper detailing), I'm not going to waste more time on this.

Answer (score 0):

From a thermodynamic perspective, the measurable quantities (specific heat, chemical potential, etc.) are defined as partial derivatives of $U$ with respect to some other variable which is uniquely defined (volume, number of particles, etc.). Thus, changing $U$ by a constant does not change any of the physically measurable quantities.

This is like adding a total time derivative to the Lagrangian, or making a gauge transformation to the electromagnetic potentials. Nothing you can physically measure will change if you make these transformations.